# Case with multiple values and without using dynamic sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

My question is trying to find a more elegant way of getting the desired results, maybe by using a `CASE` as I use here. I'm currently getting the results I need with the new requirement, but it's sorta verbose.

This was the previous query, it worked fine since it was a previous requirement. As you can see, the rows with unit (12,23,34) are being ignored:

```
declare @table table 
(
    ID varchar(5),
    pgroup varchar(5),
    Unit varchar(5),
    GeneralStatus varchar(10)
)

insert into @table (id, pgroup, unit, GeneralStatus) select 'P01', 1, 11, 'OK'
insert into @table (id, pgroup, unit, GeneralStatus) select 'P01', 1, 12, 'NOK'
insert into @table (id, pgroup, unit, GeneralStatus) select 'P01', 2, 22, 'OK'
insert into @table (id, pgroup, unit, GeneralStatus) select 'P01', 2, 23, 'NOK'
insert into @table (id, pgroup, unit, GeneralStatus) select 'P01', 3, 33, 'OK'
insert into @table (id, pgroup, unit, GeneralStatus) select 'P01', 3, 34, 'OK'
--select *From @table

select 
id,
case 
    when pgroup = 1 then 'Alpha'
    when pgroup = 2 then 'Beta'
    when pgroup = 3 then 'Gamma'
END, 
case
    when Unit = 11 then 'G1'
    when Unit = 22 then 'G2'
    when Unit = 33 then 'G3'
end,
case 
    when GeneralStatus = 'OK' then 'ENABLED'
    when GeneralStatus = 'NOK' then 'DISABLED'
end
GeneralStatus
from @table where id = ('P01') and unit in (11,22,33)
```

Unfortunately, now the requirement has changed in the sense that both rows for each `pgroup` will also be evaluated. So, in this example, for `PO1` and `pgroup` 1 (unit 11, 12) one is OK and the other NOK. This case is DISABLED. For `PO1` and `pgroup` 3 (unit 33, 34) both are OK. This case is ENABLED.

```
P01 Alpha   G1  DISABLED
P01 Beta    G2  DISABLED
P01 Gamma   G3  ENABLED
```

The solution I have now counts the rows that are `PO1` with `pgroup 1` and 'OK'. If two,  then I insert one row with status `ENABLED`. Else, `DISABLED. It's ugly, but it does the job.

I was looking for a more elegant way, maybe using `CASE`.

Comment: Have you tried `MIN`/`MAX` with `GROUP BY`? Tips: Since you are checking one column for multiple values in each `CASE` you may want to use the syntax for a _simple CASE_. It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Comment: you also need a different clause for Unit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A correlated subquery should do it.  Seems like you should be able to replace this:

```
case 
    when GeneralStatus = 'OK' then 'ENABLED'
    when GeneralStatus = 'NOK' then 'DISABLED'
end GeneralStatus
from @table where id = ('P01') and unit in (11,22,33)
```

With this:

```
case 
    when (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @table t2 
          WHERE t1.ID=t2.ID
          AND t1.pGroup=t2.pGroup
          AND GeneralStatus = 'OK') >= 2 then 'ENABLED'
    ELSE 'DISABLED'
end GeneralStatus
from @table t1 where id = ('P01') 
and unit in (11,22,33)
```

Comment: Thanks for the post, but the result would be 3 rows, not 6.

Comment: True.   Based on the wording of your question, that's what I thought you wanted.   And I'm apparently not the only one.   Can you edit your question with an example of desired results to make it clear to readers who don't look at this answer?   It's now especially unclear what you'd want the results of the unit-based column to be.

Comment: Actually, on second thought, I don't see why you think it would only result in 3 rows.   Did you try it?   Seems to me it would result in 6 rows.

Comment: Your result is 6 rows. My result would need to be 3 rows since 2 rows are used to get the overall status. pgroup1 with its 2 rows would summarize to 1 row.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can get expected result by the use of windowed version of `COUNT`:

```
select 
id,
case 
    when pgroup = 1 then 'Alpha'
    when pgroup = 2 then 'Beta'
    when pgroup = 3 then 'Gamma'
END, 
case
    when Unit = 11 then 'G1'
    when Unit = 22 then 'G2'
    when Unit = 33 then 'G3'
    when Unit = 12 then 'H1' 
    when Unit = 23 then 'H2'
    when Unit = 34 then 'H3'    
end,
CASE WHEN COUNT(GeneralStatus) OVER (PARTITION BY pgroup)
          =
          COUNT(CASE WHEN GeneralStatus= 'OK' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY pgroup)
     THEN 'ENABLED' ELSE 'DISABLED' 
END AS GeneralStatus                 
FROM mytable 
WHERE id = ('P01')
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eb8710/6)

**EDIT:** (Credit goes to @Beth)

The `CASE` expression can be simplified by checking for a `'DISABLED'` status:

```
CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN GeneralStatus <> 'OK' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY pgroup) > 0
         THEN 'DISABLED' ELSE 'ENABLED'
     END AS GeneralStatus
```

The *conditional aggregate* above checks for *at least* one non-'OK' status record within the `pgroup` partition. If such a record exists then status is `'DISABLED'`, otherwise it is `'ENABLED'`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eb8710/8)

**EDIT 2:**

To get expected result set (after OP edit) you can wrap the above in a sub-query and perform filtering on `Unit` field:

```
SELECT id, pgroup, Unit, GeneralStatus
FROM (
   SELECT id,
      CASE pgroup  
         WHEN 1 THEN 'Alpha'
         WHEN 2 THEN 'Beta'
         WHEN 3 THEN 'Gamma'
      END AS pgroup, 
      CASE Unit
         WHEN 11 THEN 'G1'
         WHEN 22 THEN 'G2'
         WHEN 33 THEN 'G3'
      END AS Unit,
      CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN GeneralStatus <> 'OK' THEN 1 END) OVER 
                (PARTITION BY pgroup) > 0
        THEN 'DISABLED' ELSE 'ENABLED' 
      END AS GeneralStatus             
   FROM mytable 
   WHERE id = ('P01') ) AS t
WHERE t.Unit IN ('G1', 'G2', 'G3')
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eb8710/14)

Comment: would it perform better to only check for status <> OK?  `CASE WHEN 
          COUNT(CASE WHEN GeneralStatus<> 'OK' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY pgroup) > 0 
     THEN  'DISABLED' ELSE 'ENABLED' `

Comment: Thanks for the post, but the result would be 3 rows, not 6.

Comment: @rbhatup Well, this is not at all clear by the way you have formulated your question.

Comment: But what if there are two "OK" and one "NOK"?

Answer (score 0):

consider

```
select 
    id,
    case 
        when pgroup = 1 then 'Alpha'
        when pgroup = 2 then 'Beta'
        when pgroup = 3 then 'Gamma'
    END, 
    case min(unit)
        when 11 then 'G1'
        when 22 then 'G2'
        when 33 then 'G3'
    end,
    case 
        when min(GeneralStatus) = 'NOK' then 'DISABLED' else 'ENABLED'
    end
    as GeneralStatus
from 
    @table 
where 
    id = ('P01')
group by id, pgroup
```

[sqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/52b0a/2)